# combine wxpython EditableListCtrl AND CheckListCtrlMixin

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Provided the code below which produces a Wxpython, Editable List Ctrl, I want to add a CheckList to it (CheckListCtrlMixin) in a new column.

Any help or examples would be appreciated on how to do this.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix

########################################################################
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    ''' TextEditMixin allows any column to be edited. '''

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]
        self.list_ctrl = EditableListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, row[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, row[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 3, row[3])
            index += 1

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Editable List Control")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ummm

```
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin,listmix.CheckListCtrlMixin):
    ''' TextEditMixin allows any column to be edited. '''

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)
        listmix.CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
```